# saxon-B trace listener control

Tags: saxon

To get tracing output from Saxon-B, you call something like:

```
processor.getUnderlyingConfiguration().setTraceListener(new XSLTTraceListener());
```

My question is, how dynamic is that? Once I've created an executable, does it capture this somehow, or can I change the listener on the fly and have it take effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really set the TraceListener on the Configuration, since it doesn't really make sense to use the same one for different transformations. Better to set it on the Controller. If you do that, then I suspect you can switch it at any time - but at your own risk, for example you won't get paired open() and close() calls.